# A modern(ish) C++ graph representation and manipulation library

Tags: open-source, library, c++, graphs

At my old workplace I had mixed experience with [Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C%2B%2B_libraries%29)'s graph library; I wasn't the person working with that code mostly, but we experienced brittleness, things changing under our feet, and a need to repeatedly refresh state for not-good-enough reasons. Yeah, I know this sounds a bit vague, but the point is I want to check out the alternatives.

So, I'm looking for a graph library which:

- Represents undirected and directed graphs.
- Does not depend on Boost at all, or at least not significantly.
- Exhibits good performance both when graphs are static (i.e. searching, looking up, iterating with and without filters, etc.).
- Exhibits good performance when graphs are manipulated - edge and vertex additions, removals, moves and updates.
- Scales well to **large, but not necessarily huge** graphs which are **spare rather than dense** - say, tens of thousands of vertices and hundreds of thousands of edges.
- Does not balk on very non-uniform vertex degrees.
- Friendly towards enriching edges and vertices with additional semantics (yes, again, being vague here not to rule answers out beforehand).
- Free and *open source*.
- Is written in [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) and later ... you know what? OK, not a strict requirement, but I would be very biased towards those.

It would also be nice if it also:

- Scales well to huge graphs.
- Performs well on sparse as well as dense graph.
- Allows you to configure its underlying representation to your performance objectives.
- Is not one of those things which malloc()'s like there's no tomorrow and leaves you trapped in a maze of pesky pointers.
- Has a not-so-viral license.
- Is actively maintained.
- Is well-documented.
- Is in wide use.

Comment: There's also [dlib](http://dlib.net/graph_tools.html)

Comment: @Antony: I don't think that meets all of my crtiera...

Comment: Sorry, I feared as much when I posted a comment rather than an answer.  I have used the Boost Graph Library a little, so I feel your pain :-(

Answer (score 14):

Some potential candidates, or close-to-being-candidates:

Might be relevant:

- [LEMON](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon/) , or **L**ibrary for **E**fficient **M**odeling and **O**ptimization in **N**etworks - A "C++ template library providing efficient implementations of common data structures and algorithms with focus on combinatorial optimization tasks connected mainly with graphs and networks." Here's a [2010 presentation](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/lemon-intro-presentation.pdf) describing LEMON.
- [GGL](http://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/software/GGL/), the **G**raph **G**rammar **L**ibrary -  . Here's the [manual](http://www.bioinf.uni-freiburg.de/Publications/Mann_GGL_13.pdf).
- [Goblin](http://goblin2.sourceforge.net/) - "A tool chain for handling graphs", including code for graph-related combinatorial optimization algorithms; laying out graphs in space (e.g. layered, orthogonal), graph composition (?), serialization to/from files, vertex and edge attributes and incidence structures. *Probably* not C++11ish nor involving templates too much.
- [SNAP](http://snap.stanford.edu/snap/index.html) - The **S**tanford **N**etwork **A**nalysis **P**latform - on one hand, seems to be pretty focused on a specific application; on the other hand, it might have a pretty-much complete graph representation and manipulation API. There's also a hint it might be based on another, lower-level, graph library.
- [NGraph](http://math.nist.gov/%7ERPozo/ngraph/ngraph_index.html) - A super-simple, single 23 KiB .hpp file, graph library.
- [digraph](https://github.com/grame-cncm/digraph) - A C++11 library for digraphs, geared for use as part of the [Faust](https://github.com/grame-cncm/faust) audio signal processing compiler.

Not relevant / not quite relevant:

- [LEDA](http://www.algorithmic-solutions.com/leda/ledak/index.htm) - A  part of a larger codebase of combinatorial algorithms and data structures of the same name. This is commercial software, and even the free edition is closed-source (you can - gasp - buy the source from them). No thank you.
- [OGDF](http://www.ogdf.net/ogdf.php?id=) - **O**pen **G**raph **D**rawing **F**ramework - Seems to be concerned more with layout, drawing of graphs on a plane. Claims to be an FOSS substitute for LEDA.
- [igraph](http://igraph.org/c/) - A C (as in: not C++) graph library created for use in network analysis. Claims to focus on performance for large-but-not-huge graphs; and seems to have seen significant development over more than a decade. [GitHub page](https://github.com/igraph/igraph). It has some [unstable-API C++ bindings](https://github.com/ntamas/igraphpp) named igraphpp.
- [NoCycle](http://nocycle.hostilefork.com/) - A library for DAG representation. It uses a compact (?) reprsentation of an adjacency map. Probably too different than what I need, and I don't think I "buy" the hype about its representation.
- [libcgraph](http://graphviz.org/pdf/cgraph.3.pdf) - Part of the [GraphViz](http://graphviz.org/) graph layout project/toolkit. Note there's also a component named libgraph in there - not sure which uses which.
- [GCT](http://www2.cedarcrest.edu/academic/csc/nlippincott/graph/index.html) - **G**raph **C**lass **T**emplates - Another one-header-file bare-bones library.

It's not impossible that some of the C libraries are good, but I don't think I'm going to spend time wrapping them in C++, not to mention the paucity of abstractions that would be effectively available with them.

See also the following Stack Overflow questions:

- [Use a Graph Library/Node Network Library or Write My Own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499878/use-a-graph-library-node-network-library-or-write-my-own)
- [Which C++ graph library should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751826/which-c-graph-library-should-i-use)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very serious project of writing a templatized, range-aware, graph library, as a proposal for addition to the C++ standard. It improves and extends ideas from Boost Graph, utilizing modern C++ facilities and mechanisms (including extensive use of ranges).

It's not in a finalized state, but can be found here: https://github.com/pratzl/graph

And the proposal is [P1709R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1709r2.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

I Suggest you the [CXXGraph](https://github.com/ZigRazor/CXXGraph) library.
It's a personal work that i start to develop more than 2 years ago with the support of other developers.

It's an open-source library and now enough mature and with good performance ( check also benchmark on your machine ).

The library is header-only and can be used with C++ 17.

The library contains all the most known algorithms.

Comment: It's your own library, which you have neglected to mention, so -1. Also, I find its design somewhat questionable.

Comment: Please declare your affiliation in the answer